# How to find a work-around when Xcode analyzer finds issues but does not show them in the files?

Tags: xcode, clang-static-analyzer

I'm having trouble with Xcode 4.5.2's analyzer. It is able to find issues:

[image]

But, while the issues are displayed on the top bar:
[image],
the issues are not shown inside the file editor.  Without this information, there is no practical way to know what the analyzer was talking about.

Is there a log file somewhere where I could find a line number for the detected issues? Any other workaround or setting tweak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workaround I can think of is [running the analyser from the command line](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build.html). That can be done directly on Xcode projects (ie, no makefile barbarism required) and should give you direct textual feedback.